# Spring boot: How to exclude static files from building .war file?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, war, static-files

I am using Spring Boot for a web application, and the remote server requires me to upload a .war file to its root directory and deploy it each time I make changes. I have managed to change the applications.properties option **spring.resources.static-locations** to use resources outside of the war file, it works properly for me.

However, when I am building the application with Maven, it still includes the static files in the generated .war file. The .war file is already 50+MB in size, and this can become a serious problem when I begin adding static image files. What can I do to exclude all static files from the .war file generated from 'maven package'?

Below is the pom.xml file for my spring boot application. Also the static files are in the directory '${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0.snapshot</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo Application</description>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>28.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Note that excluding using resources-plugin might make your IDE no longer recognize the files.

Comment: from http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html you can exclude resource files

Comment: @Tobb I saw that one but didnt find my answer, couldnt figure out where to put these <exclude> tags.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to add below block inside your build block?

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
</resources>
```

edit

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/static/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: well I did this but it seems that the .war file still contains static files, the generated WEB-INF/classes/static folder has them. Can I just prevent them from being included?

Comment: Try to remove 2nd resource tag please and also check inside static folder the code above includes static folder but as empty

Comment: please see edit.